# Does a Mongo full collection scan read every single word in a collection?

Tags: mongodb

Let's say that you don't have something indexed for some legitimate reason (like maybe you maxed out the 64 allowable indexes) and you are searching for values within only certain fields.

To go extreme, let's say each object has an `authorName` field, `bookTitles` field, and `bookFullText` field (where the content of all their novels was collected.)

If there was no index and you looked for a list of `authorNames`, would it have to read through all the content of all the fields in the entire collection, or would it read just the `authorName` fields and the names but not content of the other fields?

Comment: Documents are stored in BSON format (binary serialization format) on the disk. So, to extract a single field from a document the entire BSON document must be read from the disk and deserialized. And even more, depending on the storage engine, BSON documents can be cached as bunches, i.e. to read/write a single document the MongoDB might actually read/write a bunch of documents and keep them in internal cache.

Answer (score 1):

Fields in a document are ordered. The server stores documents as *lists* of key-value pairs. Therefore, I would expect that, if the server is doing a collection scan and field comparison, that the server will:

- Skip over all of the fields preceding the field in question, one field at a time (which requires the server to perform string comparisons over each field name), and
- **Skip over the fields after the field in question in a particular document (jump to next document in collection).**

The above applies to *comparisons*. What about *reads from disk*?

The basic database design I am familiar with separates logical records (documents in case of MongoDB, table rows in a RDBMS) from physical pages. For performance reasons the database generally will not read documents from disk, but will read *pages*. As such, it seems unlikely to me that the database will skip over some of the fields when it maps documents to pages. **I expect that when any field of a document is needed, the entire document will be read from disk.**

Further supporting this hypothesis is MongoDB's 16 MB document limit. This is rather low, and I suspect is set such that the server can read documents into memory completely without worrying that they might be very large. Postgres for example distinguishes VARCHAR from TEXT types in where the data is stored - VARCHAR data is stored inline in the table row and TEXT data is stored separately, presumably to avoid this exact issue of having to read it from disk if *any* column value is needed.

I am not a MongoDB server engineer though so the above could be wrong.

Answer (score 1):

1. BSON Documents are kept in the common case (wiredTiger snappy compressed)   in 32KB blocks in 64MB(default size ) chunks on storage  , in case your document compressed size is  48KB  , two blocks 32KB each must be loaded in memory , to be uncompressed and searched for your non indexed field which is expensive operation , moreover if you search multiple documents usually they are not written in sequential blocks increasing the demands for IOPS to your backend storage , this is why it is best to do some initial analysis and index the fields you will search mostly and create indexes , indexes(B-tree) are very effective since they are kept most of the time in memory compressed ( prefix compression) and are very fast for field search.
2. There is text indexes in mongodb that are enough for some simple text searches or you can use regex expressions.
3. If you will do full text search most of the time you better have search engine like elasticsearch which support inverse indexes in front of the database since the inverse indexes have your full text results already calculated and can give you the results times faster than similar operation using standard B-tree indexes.
4. If you use ATLAS ( the mongodb cloud service ) there is already lucene engine(inverse index) integrated that can do the fulltext search for you.

I hope my answer throw some light on the subject ... :)

Comment: Thank you.  I would take this to mean that if I have a significant number of fields (or significant content in those fields) that are beyond the ability for that table to index, that I should break them off into another table  - especially if they are rarely accessed since all they do is slow the table down?

Comment: definetely reducing the size of the document will help in such  case  ...

Comment: @spencersnygg If you are reading only one  (or fewer) field(s), then you should be using _projection_. This will return documents only with the specified field(s) from the server - this is also optimization.

Comment: So if the index points to a specific field in a document rather than containing the info itself in the index, does that mean that the whole collection has to be unpacked and read in order to find  and return that field?

Comment: @prasad_    When you say I should be using projections, are you saying skip "match" and go straight to "project"  (like load the whole doc into ram and kick out just the fields you want with Projection (assuming that you don't need match to pick the right  doc first)?  Or what do you mean?

Comment: @R2D2   If the index points to a specific document and field in the collection, does it open an entire 64mb chunk in order to access the 1, 2 or 3 compressed block that the document is in?  If the document spans 7 32kb blocks, does it know which of those seven to access or does it unpack all 7?    Once it is unpacked, does it know where that field is, or does it need to find it?   To find it, does it look at  a folder system, reading only heads of the folders, or does it read the content of each folder?  Thank you in advance.

Comment: @spencersnygg :  If you search by the index and you need fields not in the index but from the document , all the 7x 32k blocks will be loaded to memory and searched for the fields. Documents are stored in few big wiredTiger files in BSON format , operating system is caching most recent blocks from those files to file system cache so in best case the blocks are already in the file system cache , if not they will be loaded from storage ( this must be avoided as much as possible for better performance )

Comment: @spencersnygg Projection let you work with fewer fields, that allows using lesser memory, and your find query returns the fields projected to your application. Projection can also benefit in aggregation queries where a projection stage reduce the amount of data being passed to the following stages. Projection can also be used make you queries us indexes and can become covered queries.